# ASP.Net Core Data Protection API in a Clustered Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, data-protection

I'm having difficulty understanding the Data Protection API.

I'm wanting to set up some net core web applications in a clustered environment (service fabric). Previously what you'd do is just ensure that each machine has the same key in its web.config. Simple. With the new data protection API it seems a little (*lottle*!) bit more involved.

From the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest#certificate-based-encryption-with-windows-dpapi-ng) it appears that it should be as simple as setting up the Data Protection service with the appropriate certificate.

However I tried this:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // add data protection services
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        string thumbPrint = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
        serviceCollection.AddDataProtection()
            .ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG($"CERTIFICATE=HashId:{thumbPrint}", flags: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiNGProtectionDescriptorFlags.None);
        var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        // create an instance of MyClass using the service provider
        var instance = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyClass>(services);
        instance.RunSample();
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        IDataProtector _protector;

        // the 'provider' parameter is provided by DI
        public MyClass(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
        {
            _protector = provider.CreateProtector("Contoso.MyClass.v1");
        }

        public void RunSample()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter input: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            // protect the payload
            string protectedPayload = _protector.Protect(input);
            Console.WriteLine($"Protect returned: {protectedPayload}");

            // unprotect the payload
            string unprotectedPayload = _protector.Unprotect(protectedPayload);
            Console.WriteLine($"Unprotect returned: {unprotectedPayload}");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

And I just get an exception of

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.IXmlRepository' has been registered.
```

Which after some digging around turns out that it's because there is no persisted store specified for the keys.

What is advised here? Should I be persisting my keys to some central location (i.e. a share that is available to all my applications). If so, what is the reason why?

Comment: you need to be explicit as to where the keys are persisted. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview - try `.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\directory\"));` for example.

Comment: @Christo Thanks! Totally thought I updated this question, I ended up persisting my keys to AzureStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to supply an implementation of `IXmlRepository` which provides the data protection API with a place to store the keys. The `ProtectKeysWith*()` directives protect the keys at rest (in basic terms, encrypts the keys before saving them!). Additional info [here](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/issues/222).

I ended up persisting my keys to AzureStorage. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers#azure-and-redis).

```
serviceCollection.AddDataProtection()
    .ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG($"CERTIFICATE=HashId:{thumbPrint}", flags: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiNGProtectionDescriptorFlags.None)
    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(/* params */);
```

It is also worth noting that the certificate used to protect the keys *must* be stored in a certificate store and the account which the application is running under must have read access. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/issues/139#issuecomment-205898117).

Comment: How does this work when, now, each application in the cluster will attempt to roll keys all at the same-ish time?

Comment: @Moismyname keys are given 2 days after creation before becoming active, the default auto-refresh is 1 day. Apps will check for newly created keys prior to adding another, so there should be no concern. [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0)