# ASP.Net Core Data Protection API in Azure Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, ssl, data-protection

I am trying to setup Data Protection in my Azure web apps, so when I swap between staging and production, it doesn't log everyone out. I am stuck on encrypting the keys with a self-signed certificate in Azure.

My question is very much related to:
[ASP.Net Core Data Protection API in a Clustered Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368226/asp-net-core-data-protection-api-in-a-clustered-environment)
However, the answer on this does not work for me as I had already gotten this far.

---

My code works perfectly fine when I run it locally with a certificate installed to my machince, but when I deploy to my Azure web app, it wont start and just throws a generic error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' was thrown.
```

To setup my data protection, I am using the following code in **ConfigureServices**:

```
// Add data protection
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Configuration["BlobStorage:ConnectionString"]);
var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = client.GetContainerReference(Configuration["DataProtection:ContainerName"]);
container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();

services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName(Configuration["DataProtection:ApplicationName"])
    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(container, Configuration["DataProtection:BlobName"]);
    .ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG($"CERTIFICATE=HashId:{Configuration["Authentication:SingingCertThumbprint"]}",
        DpapiNGProtectionDescriptorFlags.None);
```

The certificate I am using is self-signed and I have uploaded it to Azure through the SSL certificates section on the web app (however, as suggested on other posts, I have also tried a trusted certificate - no luck).

I am using the **WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES** app setting in my Azure web app, so this is not the problem either.

Also worth noting, if I remove

```
.ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG($"CERTIFICATE=HashId:{Configuration["Authentication:SingingCertThumbprint"]}",
    DpapiNGProtectionDescriptorFlags.None);
```

Then the web app will start and run fine. 
But now my keys are obviously being stored unencrypted.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same issue. I tried changing the platform to 64bit and scaling up my app plan, but none of these worked. ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG might not be support by Azure Web App. I suggest you use ProtectKeysWithDpapi instead. The key will be encrypted by Windows DPAPI.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Makes me slightly more happy to hear I'm not the only one with this problem then..
I tried ProtectKeysWithDpapi and can confirm that works.
However, I am requiring multiple servers to be looking at this data.. So that doesn't really work as a solution for me (hence why I wanted to use the certificate).

Comment: I suggest you post this issue on Azure feedback site.  https://feedback.azure.com

Comment: even `ProtectKeysWithDpapi` doesn't seem to work for me. It still has encryption error